# Programmatically work on project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

Is it possible to do these 3 things programmatically in Visual Studio:

1. Include new files to a project
2. Change 'Build Action' on a file in a project
3. I need to do this from a command prompt application but not sure if it is possible??

Comment: A visual studio project file itself is an XML document. You could take it from there.

Comment: What is the 3rd thing?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah this is quite possible. You can create templates as .txt files with variables like $$$my_variable$$$ and just replace those with your inputted values. Can do whatever you want really. If you need an example, you could take a look at OrchardCMS, they have a command line generation tool that creates files/projects.

http://orchard.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Orchard.Web/Modules/Orchard.CodeGeneration/Services/CodeGenerationCommandInterpreter.cs

That is the file that contains the relevant code, there is a folder in that project with the templates. Hope that points you in the right direction!